# Google tag manager GTM CMS integration issue

Tags: google-tag-manager

I have a third party agency building a site for me.

They built a CMS in Wordpress, which they packaged it themselves. When I asked them to add in the GTM code, (which I would be setting up all the tags, triggers and variables in GTM), they told me they can only add in UA code, and that the system can't integrate with GTM, and claim to need extra development time and cost. Is it something I'm missing?

I've never come across a site that says can't integrate with GTM before... it's just paste in the code.. right? If it's build for UA, then GTM would work just fine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pasting in GTM code basically means adding stuff to a template (or add it via the functions file). In a plain vanilla Wordpress Installation that's a matter of minutes, certain frameworks for themes make this harder (but not by much, matter of hours, tops).

If they need to create a datalayer that might be more involved, depending on what your specifications are.

There are several extensions that implement GTM with as basic dataLayer, unless you (or they) have a chronic fear of third party extensions.

A responsible company will always check their work, so even a simple cut and paste job will create some overhead (which they are entitled to bill you for; nobody should have to work for free) but that should be a few hours.

They might have already a tested process in place to implement Universal Analytics, which would explain why they offer to do this for free/cheap.

Comment: @eike_perstorff thanks for your comments, I forgot to say, I would be the one setting up all the tags, triggers and variables. I just needed the code to be pasted in.

Comment: That's why I have gathered, but they probably would still run a full test cycle on the frontend, which might explain why they want to charge for it (ask for a quote, it should list what exactly they want money for). If this is a self-hosted Wordpress blog and you are the admin you can install a GTM extension on your own through the admin panel (although this might void your warranty if it breaks anything  on the page), which right now seems the easiest option.